# 401 (Unauthorized) When calling Sharepoint Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-search, search-api

I am currently getting this error 401 when I try to call my Sharepoint Endpoint. It occurred after I added the following Access-Control-Allow-Origin into the IIS header.
I am unsure if this is an issue with IIS or the Sharepoint Configurations, please advice. Thank you!

My Response: **GET http://www.test.com/Shared%20Documents/query%20result%20BEFORE.xml 401 (Unauthorized)**

Previously, I was facing this error but has been resolved since I added the header:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at **** from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I added the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** with a value of "*" in the HTTP Response Headers and now I am getting the 401 error.

My code:

```
  function testCall2() {
            const xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const URL= "http://test.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27BEFORE%27"

            xhr1.open("GET", URL);
            xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr1.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr1.status === 200) {
                        const response = xhr1.responseText;
                        // Process the response as needed
                        console.log(`XHR1 Success!! ${response}`);
                    } else {
                        console.error('XHR1 Error:', xhr1.statusText);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr1.send();
        }
```